# User Click Tracking Library for Desktop App

Tags: c#, desktop-application, user-input, tracking, user-tracking

We are looking into the possibility of allowing users to opt into a program where they report what button clicks etc. they do, and I was wondering if anyone can suggest a good library which already does this. Based on the way the app is implemented, we have access to the base "Button" class and can add code on the click which records the fact that the button was clicked.

What we're looking for is a library which can record all these clicks, store them locally, and then send them to us at some point in the future when the user has internet access.

Does something like this exist in an open or closed form?

Thanks,

Liron

Our app can run code in either c# or javascript, since it runs in Unity3d, but we have other desktop apps which are pure c# and would prefer a library we can run across all our applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up going with DeskMetrics, which seemed like a good fit for our needs. We also looked at TrackerBird which has some nice features which weren't necessary for our particular requirement and wasn't working within the limited requirements of Unity3d.